# Can't flag a comment on the election page?

Tags: bug, comments, election

I have been trying for a few minutes (restarting browser, using a different one, refreshing page, clearing cookies etc) now to flag a particular comment which IMO could be a bit offensive.

All I get is is

[image]

<strike>I am not sure if you can repro this so please leave a comment.</strike>

Update: bug repro confirmed.

@Lukasz L

it's a comment from [Laszlo Papp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2682142/laszlo-papp?tab=activity&sort=comments)

[image]

Under [Siddharth's nomination](https://stackoverflow.com/election/5#post-21718555)

---

It seems I'm not the only one who thinks its offensive

[image]

Comment: Could you point what comment it was? I'd try to flag it and see what happens.

Comment: Reproduced on a random comment on the election page.  Definitely seems to be a bug

Comment: @ŁukaszL. updated my original post.

Comment: Yup reproduced and I think brettdj summed it up pretty well.

Comment: Interesting that on the user activity comments page, there is no permalink to the site of the comment. Almost as if election posts aren't actually posts or something.

Comment: I have noticed that as well. I think it might have been overlooked by devs.

Comment: There's nothing racist about asking people to properly spell out words.

Comment: @Kevin, now I don't offend easily, so it doesn't bother me, but the first half of the commend is certainly true. There was just no need to bring the word "indian" into that comment. Using 'u r' instead of 'you are' happens in all english speaking countries. He only needed to say "and similar abbreviations", but he chose to imply that it was an indian trait. Anyway I see that the comment has now been removed.

Comment: @oghaza I didn't see the "Indian," I agree that part is out of line.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Moderator Elections functionality: voting UI, commenting and flagging](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/361979/moderator-elections-functionality-voting-ui-commenting-and-flagging)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to Stack Exchange employee, it's [by design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214543/152859):

> 2014-02-13: Comments on election nominations can no longer be flagged. There will be extra monitoring to ensure this doesn't result in abusive comments.

Comment: right, that's from today and my post is from yesterday. To bad none of the officials could actually come answer.. well, thanks to you now we know :)

Comment: Yep bit weird they chose to announce it this way but better than nothing...

Comment: No, it was only implemented starting today. The incident reported in this was not caused by what we set.

Comment: @Grace weird coincidence then! Think it's worth investigating by a dev, in case you will bring back the ability to flag?